# TransparentBlt running slower under Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-7, windows-10

I've got a unit test environment in which I'm timing the creation of a scatter graph, during which I'm making calls to `TransparentBlt` or, more specifically, `CDC::TransparentBlt`.

This particular test fails if the time it takes 0.07s (machine factored)

Under Windows 7, the test passes with no problems. However, after upgrading to Windows 10, the test completes in 0.19s (machine factored).

I cannot seem to find any documentation on [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/) relating to any under-the-hood change or any reason it's slower in Windows 10.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The problem seems to come from the configuration of your `.vcxproj`. Have you upgraded your compiler?

Comment: @MatthieuH could you elaborate?

Comment: In configuration of your project which **Windows SDK Version** have you ? Change can come from there.

Comment: @MatthieuH that's interesting, but why should the execution speed be dependent on the SDK?

Comment: @MatthieuH I don't believe that the used SDK has something to do with it... it onlylinks you program to some system DLLs

Comment: Do you work on Visual Studio 2019? Try to upgrade, that could help.

Comment: I suppose that the difference resides in the DWM of windows 10. There are major differences between Windows 7 and Windows 10. Please tell us why you see in a problem here? Show us some code and reasons why there is a real performance issue. Since you are no longer writing directly to the screen buffer (because of the DWM), you can't know what needs to be done to execute your drawing operations...

Comment: @MatthieuH: Why should a VS update help with a native Win32 API call? Even the C/C++ optimizer can't help you to speed up OS and GUI operations!

Comment: As IInspectable wrote: Please provide a minimal reproducible sample. Otherwise such a question gets closed, even if it is interesting... Please inform yourself "How to ask in SO"

Comment: @xMRi Can you elaborate, what do you mean difference resides in the DWM of windows 10? I quickly searched and found that windows 7 doesn't or at least can be disabled.

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be complete to be verifiable. The code provided is not. It doesn't compile nor does it showcase the benchmarking you are performing.

Comment: There can be a problem with your timer (which one are you using?).

Comment: The `l_Point` doesn't look like a compatible DC. There is posibility that Windows 10 have to translate pixel format.

Comment: It seems you are comparing 2 different machines, running 2 different operating systems. Then you use some "machine factor" to adjust for performance. Your machine factor could be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using a similar function(StretchBlt or BitBlt)? If the same problem exists, the problem has nothing to do with the API, there may be other causes.